# Rails: How to query time range, not date, values for a model in activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model with a `time` attribute. It's configuration for when a user wants to receive an email, i.e., 5 PM EST.  It's stored in the database as `21:00:00`. I'd like to query it by range. For example, I'd like every user with a reminder time between `20:55:00` and `21:05:05`.

Rails seems to handle time attributes kind of strangely because it wants to show it as a full DateTime, so the database has `21:00:00` but when loaded in rails, it shows it as 2000-01-01 17:00:00.

My code right now looks like:

```
scope :receives_report_reminder_at, -> (time) do
    start = (time - 5.minutes).strftime('%T')
    ending = (time + 5.minutes).strftime('%T')

    where(notification_report_reminder_time: start...ending)
end
```

This works in my test cases but doesn't work when I try it outside of tests. Thoughts? Is there a proper way to handle scenario or am I go about it wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see by tags, that you specified, that you use PostgreSQL database. You could use a database mechanism to convert `DateTime` type column to `time` type.

That can be done by using a double colon operator (`::`):

```
where('notification_report_reminder_time::time >= ? and notification_report_reminder_time <= ?', start, ending)
```

Comment: So simple! I had just started messing around with the transforms.